# IE11 Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer

it's seems that I'm having a frustrating problem and can't seem to find an answer.
I'm trying to get the value of the element in `<td>` tag. The **id** reaches the function but for some reason I can't get the value of it.

JS

```
function f(id)
  {
    console.log(id);
    expr=/ /gi;
    value = document.getElementById(id).value;
    value = value.replace(expr, "");

  //remaining code
  }
```

PHP

```
print "<td style=\"height:20px;\"><input $disbled type=\"text\" name=\"".$values[$i][0]."\" onChange=\"return f('".$values[$i][0]."')\" value=\"".$values[$i][1]."\" class=\"".$values[$i][2]."\"></td>\n";
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Typo, you have a `name` not an `id` in your HTML, `document.getElementById(id)` returns `null`, calling `value` on that raises the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems there:

1. Your element doesn't have an `id` at all
2. Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*.

Here's a fixed version:

```
function f(name)
{
    console.log(name);
    var expr=/ /gi;
    var value = document.querySelector('[name="' + name + '"]').value;
    value = value.replace(expr, "");
    //remaining code
}
```

#1 is fixed by using `querySelector` and an attribute selector selecting by `name`

#2 is fixed by declaring the local variables in `f`

You could also fix #1 by giving your element an `id` and sticking with `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

The input you are trying to access has not ID property defined. You shall add it in order to access the input object via getElementById().

```
<input $disbled id=\"".$id."\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$values[$i][0]."\" onChange=\"return f('".$values[$i][0]."')\" value=\"".$values[$i][1]."\" class=\"".$values[$i][2]."\">
```